# Cannot return to question list after swiping to close browser in iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I'm having a bit of trouble thinking of a good way to describe/search for this, so bear with me if it's a duplicate.

I recently realised that in the iOS app, when you click a link and a page is opened in the included browser, apart from closing the browser by hitting the “OK” button at the top (which is not always visible), swiping from left to right to ‘go back’ has the same effect.

*However*, when I close the browser in this manner, the question that I return to remains frozen for about five seconds, and even after it unfreezes, **the “<” button to return to the previous question or question list does not work**. It looks normal, but when I click on it, it changes to being greyed out and does nothing.

If I close the browser with the “OK” button, this does not happen: the question does not freeze, and the “<” button works as it should.

Is this a known bug?

(iOS 9.2.1, up to date; SE app version 1.4.3.7.)

Comment: Is [this MSO question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315887/cant-go-back-to-question-list) describing the same issue as your question here? It looks like it to me, but just to be sure.

Comment: @Kendra Yup, that is exactly the same issue. I figured this might well be a dupe. (Oddly, I can't flag this as one—tells me the original question doesn't exist?!?)

Comment: You can't flag it because they're on different sites. So, yeah, that question doesn't exist _here._ You can delete your question, or this or the other question can be flagged requesting migration and _then_ your question can be closed. Or, of course, just leave it be and not worry about it. Not that big a deal. :)

Comment: Oh, of course. MSE != MSO, duh! Thank you. I'll just leave it here with the link in the comments, then. :-)